# How can I change the awk delimiter for a part of my script?

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I have an input string that is formatted like this:

`string1;string2"string3";string4`

I want to parse this file to get the value of `string3` using `awk`.  To do this, I can first delimit by `;`, print the second segment, and then delimit by `"` and print the second segment.  Example using pipes:

```
$ echo 'string1;string2"string3";string4' | awk -F\; '{print $2}' | awk -F\" '{print $2}';
string3
```

I want to combine this into a single `awk` command, but I do not know how to change the field separator during my command.  Is there syntax I can use in `awk` to change my separator?

Comment: If you really only want to get `string3` observe, that `string3` is `$2` when input is delimited by `"` so you get it with `awk -F\" '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`split` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) inside `awk`:

```
s='string1;string2"string3";string4'
awk -F ';' 'split($2, a, /"/){print a[2]}' <<< "$s"

string3
```

As per the linked doc:

> `split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])`
>   Divide string into pieces separated by fieldsep and store the pieces in array and the separator strings in the seps array.

Comment: Cool!  How about adding a little documentation on the `split` function?: `split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])`

Comment: Cool, I had never seen the `split` function being used on `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following and let me know how it goes then.

```
echo 'string1;string2"string3";string4' | awk -F'[;"]' '{print $3}'
```

So above is creating multiple delimiters by mentioning -F option in awk and then I am setting delimiters as chars(; ") so then string3 will be 3rd field and you could merge your awk like that. I hope this helps you.

EDIT: Apologies MODs/all, I am new to this site, so I am adding another alternative for this question's answer. 
Thank you Questionmark, it encourages me. So in case you have only have two occurrences of `"` in your string and you want to get rid of this delimiter then following could help you:

```
echo 'string1;string2"string3";string4' | awk '{match($0,/\".*\"/);print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}'
```

In the above code I am matching the regex using the match functionality of awk, so once it matches the specific string then I am printing the specific match(where `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are the built-in variables in awk which will be set only when inside, the regex match is `TRUE`, so they are printed. I hope this will help too.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  That command works in this case (hence the up vote), however, it does not answer how to use use one separator after another...  The other answer is the correct answer, but your answer does work...

Comment: There's no reason to escape a double quote inside a constant regexp, they're already just literal characters. Note that your answer will find the substring between the first quote and the last quote in the record (which may span fields), not the first quoted string in `$2` as requested.